# What's the meaning of args.length?

Tags: java

recently i've come across this piece of code and i really want to understand when and how to use this args.length

```
import java.util.*; 

class Average
{

public static void main(String args[])

{

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int choice;

int a=0,min=0,max=0,x;

int n = args.length;

System.out.println("1-Sum");

System.out.println("2-Average");

System.out.println("3-Minimum");

System.out.println("4-Maximum");

System.out.println("enter your choice");

choice = sc.nextInt();

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{

a+=Integer.parseInt(args[i]);

}

switch(choice)

{

case 1: System.out.println("The sum is :" +a/n);

break

case 2: System.out.println("The Average is :" +a/n);

break

case 3: for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)

{

x=Integer.parseInt(args[i]);

if(x<Integer.parseInt(args[i+1]))

min=x;

else min=Integer.parseInt(args[i+1]);

}

System.out.println("The minimum is :" +min);

break;

case 4: for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)

{

x=Integer.parseInt(args[i]);

if(x>Integer.parseInt(args[i+1]))

max = x;

else max=Integer.parseInt(args[i+1]);

}

System.out.println("The maximum is :" +max);

break;

}

}

}
```

Comment: The most obvious guess to find the meaning of args.length, should be: the length of args, and what is args is the input array.

Comment: The answer can e found on the [JLS - Array Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7).

Comment: i would like to know more about it, like why, how and where to use it.. i.e. at what conditions we shall make use of args.length. I'm finding it a little difficult to understand this. Please help

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html. You use `args.length` when you want to know the length of the array `args`. I.e. when you want to know how many arguments were passed to your main method. For example, if the program is supposed to be called with exactly 2 arguments, but `args.length` is not 2, you can print an error message and exit.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Ahh. I'm trying to find that link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423257/what-exacly-args-length0-means?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `main()` method is initial point where java program execution starts. That's why the `main()` method is `public`, `static` and `void`. The parameters passed to `main()` method are `String args[]` i.e a String array. It is not necessarily the variable name can be only `args`, it can be any variable name i.e `String names[]`.

Now, why **args.length** is zero, when no arguments passed:

When any java program is run from command line, it is run as `java ProgName`.
The command line arguments are passed to java program as `java ProgName Arg1 Arg2`.
Here in this example, two arguments are passed to java program `ProgName`. It is simple that, the arguments are passed to java program is the same way we run a command with parameters on any operating system. The arguments are passed along with command just by separator character as "space".

Java Interpreter interprets these arguments and pass to `main()` method of java program.
When we pass arguments to java program from command line it is stored in the `args[]` String Array. As here two arguments are passed, while running java program `args[0]` and `args[1]` will be allowed, but `args[2]` will not. Same way if no arguments are passed, so java will not even allow `args[0]`.

Java interprets the command line arguments as String array, as if we pass 2 arguments it is an array with `args[0], args[1]`, if we pass 4 arguments it is an array with `args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]` and when no arguments are passed it is still an String array object with no elements.

Thus, even when we do not pass any command line arguments to java program, still the `args.length` is equal to **Zero - (0)**.

Comment: Good Explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a program, you can run the program passing [command-line arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html). If the main method is:

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

the arguments will be received in the array of `String` called `args`. Now, regarding your question:

**What does `args.length` mean?**

It's the value of the [built-in property `length`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) from arrays, which will be its fixed size. Note that arrays in Java are a special kind of objects.

Answer (score 0):

args.length is the number of elements in the args[] array.  The args[] array contains the parameters passed to the main function from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

It is the number of elements in the *args* array, that was defined in *public static main*(**String[] args**).